# Why isn't my clojure/cljs app deploying on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku and I keep getting this error:

```
The required namespace "react" is not available, it was required by "reagent/core.cljs".
```

But I have

```
"react": "17.0.2-0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2-0",
    "react-highlight.js": "1.0.7",
```

all in my package.json and I also put

```
 [cljsjs/react "17.0.2-0"]
 [cljsjs/react-dom "17.0.2-0"]
```

in my project.clj. I also did `npm install react`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

It compiles fine using shadow-cljs to my localhost, but it won't compile when I try to push to heroku. Any idea what I'm missing?

Editing to add some more details:

I made a bin/build file based on this blog post, even though I'm not using Fulcro: https://folcon.github.io/post/2020-04-12-Fulcro-on-Heroku/

I created a bin/build file that say this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
npm install
npx shadow-cljs release main
clojure -A:depstar -m hf.depstar.uberjar fulcro.jar
```

I added this to my `shadow-cljs.edn` file:

```
;; v-- and this!
                       :release {:compiler-options {:optimizations :advanced}}}
```

And it also said to add something to my `deps.edn` file, but I don't have one so I didn't.

I also did the buildpack step to add the clojure and nodejs buildpacks, although I'm not using nodejs to my knowledge.

Comment: Do you have more information regarding your Heroku setup? The problem likely is just a missing `npm install` before starting shadow-cljs. shadow-cljs does not support CLJSJS packages so adding them to your `project.clj` does nothing and you can remove them.

Comment: I created bin/build file and added npm install to it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Still not enough information. Basically you need to verify that in the directory of your `shadow-cljs.edn` also contains a `node_modules/react` directory. `shadow-cljs` should tell you where it looked, verify that directory actually exists and is readable by `shadow-cljs`.

Comment: Thanks for responding Thomas. I ended up adding a bin/build file that did the npm install and all that and got it to install everything. Now the app shows up but it's not reading my config.edn file. I'm going to make a new post to see what that issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was very easy to fix.
You need to first specify buildpacks nodejs, and after it only clojure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding and ordering multiple build packs is now possible using the web admin console under "Settings". The NodeJS buildpack must be above the clojure buildpack, so that NPM is run first.

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://clojurians-log.clojureverse.org/shadow-cljs/2019-08-25):
`npm install react react-dom create-react-class`